# VSCode : Recover overwritten file after bug

Tags: visual-studio-code

when I opened VSCode with my current jupyter Notebook,
it asked me wether I want to overwrite my notebook with a newer version. It turned out, that it took a version from a month ago and overwrote my progress (including the timeline).

Beyond the question, how it is possible that such a bug appears in VSCode, I need to know, wether I can recover my old notebook.

I do not find any file in my Code\Backups, but several files in the Cache_Data whose date would match the saving times of my old notebooks. How do I recover my notebook?

Comment: do you use version control or backup outside VSC

Comment: No, unfortunately not